# What is meant by the term 'state' in a finite-state machine?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, finite-model-theory

What is meant by the term 'state' in a finite-state machine?

I have not seen a proper definition on the web and am looking for a university-level answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/85023/98) pretty much covers it. Duplicate?

Comment: It is just an abstract notion capturing the various situations a system might be in. There are lots of proper definitions on the web for the states of a finite state device, but they only capture the fact there are finitely many of them states. I really wonder what you are looking for? Perhaps a [university level] dictionary  might be a better help: "*a condition or stage in the physical being of something*" (Merriam-Webster) "*The particular condition that someone or something is in at a specific time*" (Oxford)

Answer (score 1):

A state is simply an assignment of all possible variables of a system to values. A state transition then means a transition from one possible set of values of variables to another set of values.

To see how this might be useful, imagine a set of two switches $S$ and a light bulb $B$ that are connected to emulate some unknown logical gate. If you want to find out what that gate is, you can use a state machine model:

Say $I = \{S,B\} $

Initial State: $I = \{\{0,0\},0\}$

State transitions:

$\{\{0,0\},0\} \rightarrow \{\{1,0\},1\} \rightarrow \{\{0,1\},1\} \rightarrow \{\{1,1\},0\} $

It is evident that every state is just a set of different possible values of $I.$

By looking at the values of $B$ for a set of values of $S$, You can easily deduce that the system emulates a XOR gate.

Answer (score -1):

If you have done some programming in some language , then the current executing instruction can be considered as the state in automata,

Like if you consider this python code :

```
print('Hello') - (A)
print('World') - (B)
```

then it simply going from A->B which will be giving you the output of `"Hello World"` on your console.

So you are going from one state to another on some input or terminating the automation if nothing is left to consume.